# Unable to Receive DNS Responses

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

Operating System - Windows 2008 R2
Service Pack - Service Pack 1
IP Address - 10.50.1.111
Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0
Gateway - 10.50.1.1
DNS Server - 10.50.1.90

Other servers are using 10.50.1.90 as their DNS server and are not having any problems. This tells me that the problem is not with the DNS server.

I can ping 10.50.1.90.

The firewall is disabled.

If I run nslookup and query the name of 10.50.1.90 (OfficeDC1.office.org) it says, "*** [10.50.1.90] can't find OfficeDC1".

If I run nslookup and change the server to 8.8.8.8 and query google.com it says, "*** [8.8.8.8] can't find google.com: No response from server".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem had nothing to do with DNS. The problem was the TCP stack was corrupted. I uninstalled and reinstalled the network adapters and ran the command below.

```
netsh winsock reset
```

After the command ran I restarted the server and the DNS problems were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting?
Or specifically restarting the service?

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and restart DNS Client service?

Comment: Yes. msconfig shows that it is configured to start normally. The DNS Client service is running. The DNS cache has been flushed and registered multiple times over the course of 6 hours. The server has been restarted twice.

Comment: You said that you changed the local machines DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and saw the same issue?

Comment: I did not change the DNS server configuration on the NIC, but I opened nslookup and manually changed the DNS server for the session in nslookup to 8.8.8.8. Yes the issue was the same.

Comment: @user5870571 use debug option and then show result. For example: nslookup --> set debug --> server 8.8.8.8. (or 10.50.1.90). If you have "DNS request timed out.    timeout was 2 seconds. timeout (2 secs)" This means that you can not access the DNS server on port 53.

Comment: The server has since been shut off but it should be back on tomorrow. I will give that a try and let you know what the results are.

Comment: It may also mean that even though packets can get out on port 53, the response packet may not be able to get in.  Check firewalls.

Comment: @KarenB I already checked the firewalls. I went so far as to turn the firewalls off to rule out any problems with response packets being accepted. With the firewalls turned off there was no change in symptoms.